# What Is equivalent to a [a < 0] = 0 in Theano?

Tags: python, theano

What is the equivalent to NumPy's `a[a < 0] = 0` in Theano (tensor variable)?
I want all my matrix elements that are smaller than a number equal to zero.

Comment: The relevant location in the documentation appears to be http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/basic.html#indexing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This work:

```
import theano
a=theano.tensor.matrix()
idxs=(a<0).nonzero()
new_a=theano.tensor.set_subtensor(a[idxs], 0)
```

Do not forget, Theano is a symbolic language. So the variable a isn't changed in the user graph. It is the new variable new_a that contain the new value and a still have the old value.

Theano will optimize this to work inplace if possible.

Comment: Thanks. and also work with "a = T.where( a < 0, 0, a)"

Answer (score 1):

This also works, and can also add upper bound limit

```
import theano
import theano.tensor as T
a = T.matrix()
b = a.clip(0.0)
```

or if you want upper bound as well, you might like to try:

```
b = T.clip(a, 0.0, 1.0)
```

where 1.0 the place one want set upper bound.

check the documents [here](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/basic.html)